# Android - read all sensors every X minutes

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager, sensors

I need to read all the device sensors in my app.
I've made an Android Service that implements the `SensorEventListener` interface.
Here is the code:

```
    public class SensorService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "SensorService";
    private SensorManager sensorManager = null;
    private Sensor sensor = null;




    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
        for (Sensor sensor : sensors)
        {

            sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();  
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // nothing

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

                //do something with values
        ...

        // unregisterthe sensor
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this,event.sensor);

                // stop the service
        stopSelf();

    }

    }

}
```

But the problem is that I only want to read the values every minute, beacuse of the drain of battery. So, I decided to call the
service using the `AlarmManager` from the activity, every minute:

```
(My Activity)
...
    public void startService(View view) {

//Starts the service every minute

    AlarmManager scheduler = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SensorService.class );
    PendingIntent scheduledIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    scheduler.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000, scheduledIntent);

}
public void stopService(View view) {
    //Stops the servicee
    AlarmManager scheduler = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,SensorService.class );
    PendingIntent scheduledIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    scheduler.cancel(scheduledIntent);

}
...
```

I start the service with the `AlarmManager`, then I read the values and I call the stopSelf method ir order to stop the service.

The problem is the values read are old because the sensor doesn't changed because the service is stopped (I think so). 
The other problem is the stopSelf method is called every time a sensor is read, instead of being called once.

I don't know if there is a better way for doing this. I'd really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have a very similar problem.